# How would you construct an XSRF attack using an iframe?

Tags: attacks

I know that you can easily trigger a series of POST/GET to a target website using an iframe as I have done it in the past to manipulate session variable on my sites.

My question is more about : what information could I get from another website that I load into an iframe?

If I'm right, the same origin policy is supposed to block me from reading the iframe content if the page I load into the iframe is not from the same domain as the page containing the iframe. Is there any ways to do bypass that?

If there are information that I absolutely need to read on the page, like unique form submission token, how would you mount the attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing that matches your question is a [Clickjacking attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) (UI redress).

This is where you load another website within an IFrame that contains a button for the user to click. For example you (the attacker) could load the URL on a user's bank's website in the form `https://www.example.com/money_transfer.aspx?to_account=12345&amount=1000000` where `12345` is your account number. If they are already logged into their bank and the response is a HTML form containing a single `Transfer` button, you could draw your own UI in your outer page that would replace the button with one that said `Get a free iPad now!`.

When the unsuspecting user clicks the free iPad button on your site, they are in fact clicking the Transfer button on their bank's website to transfer the money.

This sort of attack can be defeated by setting the [`X-Frame-Options`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options) HTTP header which modern browsers will obey and stop your website from being loaded within a frame.

Accessing the loaded IFrame using scripting is prohibited due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - the only way round this if the user is using some old unsupported browser, or a browser containing a vulnerability where the origin is not properly checked.

The other possibility is a [Rebinding Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) - the scope of this is usually limited as the cookies sent to the rebound IP will be the same as to the attacker's domain.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a programmer question, but you get the child frame's document like:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_frames.asp

You access the frames by names. So if your iframe's name="myFrame", you access it like:

window.frames["myFrame"].document

There is also a contentWindow property on iframe.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

As for what you can do within the laws of the same origin policy, I'm not too familiar with that but HLMGTFY: http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy